# How can I write assertion for hidden alerts in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have to assert a hidden alert in Selenium IDE. The commands suggested by IDE failed. Below mentioned is the html tag for the error message. Thanks for the Help!

```
    <article class="alertify-log alertify-log-error alertify-log-show alertify-log-   hide">ERROR: User name and password doesn't match. Please try again.</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asserts that the article is present:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=article[class*='hide'][class*='alertify-log-error']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Asserts the text is present:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>css=article[class*='hide'][class*='alertify-log-error']</td>
    <td>ERROR: User name and password doesn't match. Please try again.</td>
</tr>
```